# How should pre-tax contributions to an HSA show up on a W2?

Tags: united-states, hsa, form-w-2

How should pre-tax contributions to an HSA account show up on a W2 from an employer?   I thought they would show up like 401k or similar but that doesn't appear to be the case.

If I made $50K and put $2K of that into an HSA pre-tax and my company adds $1K, should I expect this:

Salary: $50K
HSA: $2K

or

Salary: $48K
HSA: $2K

or

Salary: $48K
*no mention of hsa*

or what?   Does the gift of $1k Show up anywhere on my W2?  Does the $2K pre-tax contributions show up on my W2?    Currently, I'm seeing "Salary $48K with no mention of hsa" - Is the company doing things right or wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My W-2 included additional info so that it was easier to understand:

It explained the numbers for Box 1 (wages tips an other compensation, Box 3 (Social security wages), Box 5 Medicare wages , Box 16 State wages:

For box 1 it was

- Gross pay
- Less 401K (D-Box 12)
- Less Medical FSA
- Less other Cafe
- Less Cafe 125 HSA (W-box 12)

It included the numbers for each cell.

Note the number in W Box 12 for the HSA was my contibution plus their contribution. But the number in the calculation of Box 1 was only my contribution.

Answer (score 8):

Looking at the IRS guidelines for W2 forms and the HSA section, I found IRS documentation to support mhoran_psprep's answer.

1. Employer's contribution should not appear in box 1, 3, nor 5 of the W2.
2. Employee's contribution through a cafeteria plan that is believed to be excluded from income should not appear in box 1, 3, nor 5 of the W2.
3. All employer contributions should be in box 12 of the W-2 with code "W".
4. All employee contributions through a cafeteria plan should be in box 12 of the W-2 with code "W" also.

From: http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/iw2w3.pdf

> **Health savings account (HSA).** An employer's  contribution (including
>   an employee's contributions  through a cafeteria plan) to an
>   employee's HSA is not  subject to federal income tax withholding or
>   social  security, Medicare, or railroad retirement taxes (or FUTA 
>   tax) if it is reasonable to believe at the time of the payment  that
>   the contribution will be excludable from the  employee's income.
>   However, if it is not reasonable to  believe at the time of payment
>   that the contribution will be  excludable from the employee's income,
>   employer  contributions are subject to federal income tax 
>   withholding, social security and Medicare taxes (or  railroad
>   retirement taxes, if applicable), and FUTA tax and  must be reported
>   in boxes 1, 3, and 5 (use box 14 if  railroad retirement taxes apply),
>   and on Form 940,  Employer's Annual Federal Unemployment (FUTA) Tax 
>   Return.
>
> You must report all employer contributions (including  an
>   employee's contributions through a cafeteria plan) to  an HSA in box
>   12 of Form W-2 with code W. Employer  contributions to an HSA that are
>   not excludable from the  income of the employee also must be reported
>   in boxes 1,  3, and 5. (Use box 14 if railroad retirement taxes
>   apply.)
>
> An employee's contributions to an HSA (unless made  through a
>   cafeteria plan) are includible in income as  wages and are subject to
>   federal income tax withholding  and social security and Medicare taxes
>   (or railroad  retirement taxes, if applicable). Employee contributions
>   are deductible, within limits, on the employee's Form 
>   1040. For more information about HSAs, see Notice  2004-2, Notice 2004-50, and Notice 2008-52. Notice  2004-2, 2004-2 I.R.B. 269, is
>   available at www.irs.gov/irb/ 2004-02_IRB/ar09.html. Notice 2004-50,
>   2004-33 I.R.B.  196, is available at www.irs.gov/irb/2004-33_IRB/
>   ar08.html. Notice 2008-52, 2008-25 I.R.B. 1166, is  available at
>   www.irs.gov/irb/2008-25_IRB/ar10.html. Also  see Form 8889, Health
>   Savings Accounts (HSAs), and  Pub. 969.

Answer (score 0):

Under a cafeteria plan, the employee's contribution to an HSA is not taxable income and therefore no tax deduction can be achieved on the amounts contributed. That makes sense.

Further, the employee's contribution, I believe, may be considered an employer's contribution under those circumstances. Look at Form 5498-SA: employee contributions to an HSA equal contributions on that from MINUS those on your W-2 Box 12 "W". For most people the two amounts are the same. You can only deduct the difference.

Answer (score -2):

My, how clear (our US tax documentation is)!  Based on my experience, box 3 & 5 are earnings minus HSA contribution.  Box 1 is earnings minus HSA and minus 401K.  There may be other minuses that don't apply to me.

So if you made $50K, and contributed $5K to IRA, and $2K to HSA, and employer contributed $1K to your HSA, box 1 would be either $42K or $43K.  Box 12 (C) would be $5K, and box 12(W) would be $2K???  Perhaps box 12 (DD) is the $2K plus $1K =  $3K

My opinion, I could be wrong.

Comment: How did you turn "Box 1 is earnings minus HSA and minus 401K" (correct) into "if you contributed $5k to IRA"... it will adjust box 1 (incorrect) ?

Comment: @BenVoigt: if the IRA is SAR-SEP-IRA or SIMPLE-IRA, but those should be box 12 code F or S, not C.